# Exchange Webservices Forwards Mail to wrong mail address in C#

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

I try to forward a Message through EWS with the following code:

```
EmailAddress[] adresses = { "servicedesk@example.com", "allschwil_sox@example.com" };
newEmailMessage.Forward("Account access has been removed according to attached Report", adresses);
```

example.com beeing our company domain. For some unknown reason, the email is not forwarded to our domain (servicedesk@example.com) but to another company: servicedesk@lifetech.com. Does anyone know how that can happen?

Allschwil_Sox@example.com got sent correctly to allschwil_sox@example.com

[image]

Comment: You had better ask the administrator instead. It is no coincident that `lifetech` is a managed network and managed security services provider.

Comment: I don't know if thats true.. entering lifetech.com in the browser actually reroutes to my companies homepage. Therefore I guess lifetech somehow is part of my company. still its bothersome that the message is beeing sent to wrong mail adress